# Get list of column names with values > 0 for every row in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to add a column `result` to a polars `DataFrame` that contains a list of the column names with a value greater than zero at that position.

So given this:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"apple": [1, 0, 2, 0], "banana": [1, 0, 0, 1]})
cols = ["apple", "banana"]
```

How do I get:

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ apple ┆ banana ┆ result              │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---                 │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ list[str]           │
╞═══════╪════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1      ┆ ["apple", "banana"] │
│ 0     ┆ 0      ┆ []                  │
│ 2     ┆ 0      ┆ ["apple"]           │
│ 0     ┆ 1      ┆ ["banana"]          │
└───────┴────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

All I have so far is the truth values:

```
df.with_columns(pl.concat_list(pl.col(cols).gt(0)).alias("result"))

shape: (4, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬────────────────┐
│ apple ┆ banana ┆ result         │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---            │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ list[bool]     │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1      ┆ [true, true]   │
│ 0     ┆ 0      ┆ [false, false] │
│ 2     ┆ 0      ┆ [true, false]  │
│ 0     ┆ 1      ┆ [false, true]  │
└───────┴────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: You've done the tricky part by getting the Boolean values. You can get the list of column names using `df.columns`. You could write a function to get the columns based on the list of booleans, but if you convert the columns array into a numpy array, you can use the Boolean array as a mask to filter the columns. Something like `new_columns = np.array(df.columns)[bool_array]` should work.

Comment: @SurajShourie it's in the question :) (first Dataframe output)

Comment: ooh I misread that statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way: you can use [`pl.when`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when) with `pl.lit` in the `concat_list` to get either the literal column names or `null`s, then thanks to [`list.eval`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.eval.html#polars.Expr.list.eval), do a `drop_nulls` afterwards (each list is treated as a `pl.Series` within the `eval`, thus all `pl.Series` methods are available):

```py
df.with_columns(
    result=pl.concat_list(
        pl.when(pl.col(col) > 0).then(pl.lit(col)) for col in df.columns
    ).list.eval(pl.element().drop_nulls(), parallel=True)
)
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ apple ┆ banana ┆ result              │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---                 │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ list[str]           │
╞═══════╪════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1      ┆ ["apple", "banana"] │
│ 0     ┆ 0      ┆ []                  │
│ 2     ┆ 0      ┆ ["apple"]           │
│ 0     ┆ 1      ┆ ["banana"]          │
└───────┴────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: `list.drop_nulls()` will be available in `0.19.4` https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11272

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using melt to move the column names into the data

**Edit** in part with @jqurious's tip I augmented my original method to not need the self join.

```
cols = ["apple", "banana"]
(
    df
    .with_row_count('i')
    .melt(id_vars='i')
    .group_by('i',maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        # this dict restores the original columns from before melt
        **{x:pl.col('value').filter(pl.col('variable')==x).first() 
                for x in df.columns}, 
        result=pl.col('variable')
                .filter(
                    (pl.col('value')>0) & 
                    (pl.col('variable').is_in(cols)) 
                    # the 2nd filter is in case there are columns 
                    # you don't want in the result, 
                    # if you want all the columns, as in the example,
                    # then this isn't necessary
                    )
        )
    .drop('i')
)
```

**Original ansewr:**

```
df.with_row_count('i').join(
    df
        .with_row_count('i')
        .melt(id_vars='i')
        .filter(pl.col('value')>0)
        .group_by('i')
        .agg(result=pl.col('variable')),
    on='i', how='left'
).drop('i').with_columns(pl.col('result').fill_null([]))

shape: (4, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ apple ┆ banana ┆ result              │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---                 │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ list[str]           │
╞═══════╪════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1      ┆ ["apple", "banana"] │
│ 0     ┆ 0      ┆ []                  │
│ 2     ┆ 0      ┆ ["apple"]           │
│ 0     ┆ 1      ┆ ["banana"]          │
└───────┴────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

I've seen in other scripts that `pl.element` inside `.list.eval` can be surprisingly slow so this might be worth a shot even though I'll concede it isn't particularly nice to look at.

**Performance:**

Setup:

```
n=10_000_000
df=pl.DataFrame({'apple':np.random.randint(0,5,n),
                 'banana':np.random.randint(0,5,n)})
```

My original method took `21.4 s ± 1.36 s per loop`

My new method took `14.1 s ± 296 ms per loop`

@Wayoshi's method took `20.9 s ± 606 ms per loop`

Comment: If you maintain order on the group_by and move the filter inside: `.agg(result = pl.col('variable').filter(pl.col('value') > 0))` you could get rid of the join, drop, fill_null and add the result directly as a new column. Not sure if there would be a performance difference.

Comment: That's a good idea. I never think to use filters inside expressions. I'll try it Monday.

Comment: @jqurious I made some tweaks based on your tip and added a performance comparison. I'm not sure how you envisioned getting rid of the `drop` but it shouldn't matter to performance as obviating the join did.

Comment: Interesting stuff! Thanks for the performance comparison. Ah, I had an extra `.with_columns` / `.select` which I guess means the drop behaviour is still there, just written differently. e.g. `df.with_columns(df.with_row_count().melt('row_nr').group_by('row_nr', maintain_order=True).agg(result = pl.col('variable').filter(pl.col('value') > 0)).select("result"))`