# polars - get name of column containing max value per row

Tags: python-polars

In `pandas` I have the option of doing the following to get the name of the column containing the maximum value for each row:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]})

df['Largest'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Which gets me:

|  | a | b | Largest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | b |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | b |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | a |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | a |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | a |

How can I do this kind of operation in `polars`? There doesn't seem to be an `idxmax` method, and `max_horizontal` seems to only return the value rather than any indexing information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Post 0.19

```py
def arg_max_horizontal(*columns: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
        pl.concat_list(columns)
        .list.arg_max()
        .replace({i: col_name for i, col_name in enumerate(columns)})
    )


print(df.with_columns(Largest=arg_max_horizontal("a", "b")))
```

### Pre-0.19

```py
def arg_max_horizontal(*columns: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
        pl.concat_list(columns)
        .list.arg_max()
        .map_dict({i: col_name for i, col_name in enumerate(columns)})
    )
print(df.with_columns(Largest=arg_max_horizontal("a", "b")))
```

Then you'll get

```py
Out[11]:
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ Largest │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ b       │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ b       │
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ a       │
│ 4   ┆ 2   ┆ a       │
│ 5   ┆ 1   ┆ a       │
└─────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: This is perfect! I'd nearly got somewhere with an approach similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77158771) but your approach seems much faster. Thank you!

Comment: this might be a good feature request by the way if you want to open an issue on the Polars github

Comment: As of v0.19this no longer works... See https://docs.pola.rs/releases/upgrade/0.19/#aggregation-functions-no-longer-support-horizontal-computation

Comment: You could even simplify `{i: col_name for i, col_name in enumerate(columns)}` to `dict(enumerate(columns))`.